# Android not playing song when a URI is set as datasource

Tags: android, media-player

I am developing a music application and want to play a song when a URI is set as datasource, but setDataSource is not accepting the String. I mean how can we write the URI for a particular ID.

Here is the code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.reset();
String sel = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID+"=166";
mp.setDataSource(context,sel);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Here 166 is the ID of a particular song in my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your URI properly

Use

```
Uri fileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 166);
mp.setDataSource(context, fileUri);
```

Use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` if your audio is using being stored on your device's internal storage

Comment: Thanks. Its working great. Instead 2nd line should be changed to `mp.setDataSource(context,fileUri);`

Comment: Yup! Updated to include the context as an argument